# In Suits why does it matter that Mike hasn't gone to Harvard?

Tags: plot-explanation, suits

I don't understand, because even though Mike hasn't gone to Harvard, it is expressed that Jessica can waive the rule as she did with Rachel going to Columbia.

Comment: Related: http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/30740/49.

Answer (score 1):

In many states, including New York, it is required that a person obtain a law degree before being allowed to take the BAR exam.  Mike has only ever taken the exam for other people.  Then, in order to be a representative in legal proceedings, a person must have passed the BAR.

Additionally, there is the prestige that the firm receives from only employing Harvard graduates.

Answer (score 0):

I think it matters more that he does not have a formal law degree than not going to Harvard. He cannot practice law without a formal law degree and that can get him into deep trouble.

Comment: but he has already passed the BAR